# Why "vlan: 3 parent interface: en0"

Tags: iproute2, ifconfig

I have created a VLAN:

Linux

```
vconfig add en0 3
ip addr add 192.168.126.5/24 dev en0.3
ip link set up en0.3
can be translated to macOS by e.g.
```

MacOS

```
ifconfig vlan0 create
ifconfig vlan0 vlan 3 vlandev en0
ifconfig vlan0 inet 192.168.126.5 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And I can now see, from `ip link show` that I have a VLAN saying:

```
vlan0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1496
    options=6063<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    inet 192.168.126.5 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.126.255
    vlan: 3 parent interface: en0
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Why `vlan: 3 parent interface: en0` as I have only one physical enterface - also stated "en0"?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: Information on what the nummer 3 induceres

Comment: [Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). What problem do you have to start with? What is the end state of the system that you want to achieve? How it should behave?

Comment: OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG

Comment: Ahh, sorry maybe "induceres" confused you, it shoud have ben indicates - "What the number 3 indicates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why vlan: 3 parent interface: en0 as I have only one physical enterface - also stated "en0"?

It indicates that it's vlan number 3, on the interface `en0`. VLAN's are tied to a physical interface.

In your case you have only one, but it's common to have multiple Ethernet interfaces, in which case this is crucial information for knowing where the VLAN goes.